# React Native archiving error - /ios/index.js. not found

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to archive an iOS react native app with Xcode but it give me these errors:

- error The resource `/Users/andreacolombo/Desktop/projectName/ios/index.js` was not found..
- 'error: File `/Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-bxaxxwslkvjsrgcpsonpisxutuei/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/projectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/appName.app/main.jsbundle` does not exist. This must be a bug with'

My react native version is: 0.59.10.

If i build and run it in release configuration, it give me the same errors

With an other mac it works so it is not a code problem..

I'm going crazy...

What could be?
Thanks!